# request-reply spring integration jms inbound and http outbound

Tags: spring-integration

```
<int-jms:channel id="inputChannel"  queue-name="WorkRequest"/>
<int-jms:inbound-gateway request-channel="inputChannel" request-destination-name="WorkRequest" extract-request-payload="true" reply-timeout="12000000"/>
<int:chain input-channel="inputChannel">

    <int-http:outbound-gateway
          url="http://localhost:8080/Validate.php?fileid={foo}"
          mapped-request-headers="jms*,reply*,HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS"
          http-method="GET"
          reply-timeout="12000000" extract-request-payload="true">
         <int-http:uri-variable name="foo" expression="headers.fileid"/>
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
</int:chain>
```

The response from http outbound is not routed to temporary JMS queue. I would like to know how should I redirect to the proper queue. I used header-enricher with replyTo but it did not work. Please help.  The consumed ActiveMQTextMessage has temporary queue where the response needs to be posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you explain why you have a JMS-backed channel between the JMS inbound gateway and the HTTP outbound gateway? If you remove that (rely on a direct channel), the headers should pass along  as the HTTP response is used to create the JMS reply.

Comment: Right - just change `<int-jms:channel.../>` to simply `<int:channel/>`. The way you have it now, you have two consumers of `WorkRequest` (the gateway writes the message back out to the same queue by sending it to `inputChannel`).

Comment: Thanks! it worked. But I'm getting the following error now. "Cannot convert object of type [org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity] to JMS message. Supported message payloads are: String, byte array, Map<String,?>, Serializable object." I'm newbie to Spring and Java

Comment: Use the `expected-response-type` atribute on the outbound gateway. For example if you are just getting text back, try adding `expected-response-type="java.lang.String"` to the outbound gateway.

Comment: I added the <int:object-to-string-transformer /> and it worked. However setting expected-response-type="java.lang.String" to the outbound gateway did not not work for me.